# Why Wikipedia doesn't allow cross-linking?

Tags: wikipedia

I'm trying to understand inconsistency on Wikipedia structure.

For example there is article called [Bar and Bat Mitzvah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bar_and_Bat_Mitzvah) (EN) which consist two terms together: Bar Mitzvah and Bat Mitzvah.

This article consequently linked with over 30 different language articles, however most of them describe only one term which is Bar Mitzvah.

Then there is another branch of linked articles under second term describing [Bat Mitzvah](http://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bat_micwa) which is linked with over 10 different languages, however they're not linked to the English articles, because it's not possible.

When I've tried to [link](http://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q2365689#sitelinks-wikipedia) English version to Polish version, I've got the error:

> The link enwiki:Bar and Bat Mitzvah is already used by item Bar and Bat Mitzvah (Q75673). You may remove it from Bar and Bat Mitzvah (Q75673) if it does not belong there or merge the items if they are about the exact same topic.

This is very confusing how it actually should work.

It seems some of these articles are disconnected from the rest, because Wikipedia doesn't allow cross-linking, so it's actually difficult to find them.

Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a restriction of Wikidata itself, as a single page from one wiki can only be linked to only one item in Wikidata. Such issues are usually due to different policies by different Wikipedias, as such it is always best to [report such issues to the community](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Interwiki_conflicts) and have them work out something for you.